# Taylor series of $2^\frac{x_\text{ideal}-x}{d}$

Tags: taylor-expansion

I have a question about Taylor series

I need to compute Taylor series of this: $2^\frac{x_\text{ideal}-x}{d}$

The f'(x) is: $-\dfrac{\ln\left(2\right){\cdot}2^\frac{x_\text{ideal}-x}{d}}{d}$

The f$''$(x) is $\dfrac{\ln^2\left(2\right){\cdot}2^\frac{x_\text{ideal}-x}{d}}{d^2}$

and so on. Source: https://www.derivative-calculator.net/

So the formula will be like:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{30}\frac{\frac{\left(2^{\frac{\left(x_{ideal}-x\right)}{d}}\cdot\ln\left(2\right)^{n}\right)}{d^{n}}}{n!}$$

But it seems not correct.

The correct is:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{30}\frac{\left(\frac{\left(x_{ideal}-x\right)}{d}\cdot\ln\left(2\right)\right)^{n}}{n!}$$

Here is the demo. The 6, 9 and 10
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/twdf0jy77g?lang=vi

Can anyone explain for me why?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use mathjax rather than images. This [guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a good start. Also, use the [meta read](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and enhance your question. It helps to include context (i.e., your attempts, motivation, etc).

Comment: @Laufen thank you. I just edited the question. Could you help?

Comment: Is $x_{\text {ideal}}$ meant to be a constant?  If so, I suggest using a simpler notation for it.  In any case:  rewrite your function as $C_1e^{C_2x}$ for suitable constants $C_1, C_2$ and use the standard Taylor series for $e^x$.

Comment: @lulu yeah. $x_{ideal}$ and $d$ are constant. I included in the demo. Could you take a look

Comment: Note:  In my prior comment I assumed that you wanted the series expansion near $0$, but you never specified that.  If, instead, you meant the expansion near $x_{\text {ideal}}$ follow my comment as before, only get it in the form $C_1e^{C_2(x-x_{\text {ideal}})}$.

Comment: Sorry but you are mixing different things. let $x_{ideal}$ be $x_0$. Are you asked to give a Taylor development around at the origin or around $x_0$. Besides, if it is around $x_0$ the formula is the sum of terms $\dfrac{f^{n}(x_0)}{n!}(x-x_0)^n$ (you don't have terms in $(x-x_0)$ in the fraction).

Comment: @lulu yeah.  I want the series expansion near 0, you are right

Comment: @JeanMarie $d$ and  are constant. $d$ = 0.05 and  = 0.5

Comment: Have you realized that $2^{\dfrac{x_0-x}{d}}=K2^{\dfrac{-x}{d}}=Ke^{ln(2)\dfrac{-x}{d}}$ with $K:=2^{\dfrac{x_0}{d}}$ ? In this way you just have to use the Taylor expansion of the exponential function.

Comment: @JeanMarie Could you write an answer? I need to give you my vote

Comment: I have done it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$2^{\dfrac{x_0-x}{d}}=K2^{-\tfrac{x}{d}}=Ke^{-ln(2)\tfrac{x}{d}} \ \text{with} \ K:=2^{\dfrac{x_0}{d}}$$

Now consider the Taylor expansion of

$$\exp(X)=1+X+X^2/2+X^3/3!+\cdots \ \text{with} \ X:=-ln(2)\tfrac{x}{d}$$

Comment: thank you. awesome

Comment: I am too old since I never saw during my studies $x:=$. But one thing I never see anymore is $x==$. Do you know why ? Cheers :-)

Comment: @Claude Leibovici Yes, computer science notations and concepts have a strong osmotic pressure on mathematics (some will even say that they pervade maths)... I remember having met notation $x:=$ with Pascal language, but I think it comes from Algol. The same for $==$ but it can make sense only in computer science issues... Cheers.

Comment: $x==$ was a standard notation in mathematics .... when I was young (looong time ago). Now, I remember for Algol.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici What was it for ? I don't remember having seen it in maths.

Comment: $x==y \implies$ $x$ is strictly equal to $y$.